# Javascript - How to save <li> elements that are added to <ul> after refresh>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a basic to-do app where I can just simply add, complete and delete tasks.

I have the core functionality working but I'm trying to figure out how to save the tasks the user adds to the  after the page has been refreshed - as the app will be pretty useless if the user can't see their created tasks after they refresh the page.

I'm new to front-end development, so I'm open to all opinions and help you guys can offer.

Many thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">

    <h1>To-Do List <i class="far fa-check-square"></i></h1>

    <hr class="hr_style">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a new todo">

    <ul></ul>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
// Save todos list after refresh



// Line-through To_Do's when clicked on
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

// Delete button to remove task from list
$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event){
    // Use .parent() to include the whole <li> element to fade out once deleted
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(function() {
        // Will delete the element from the page instead of hiding it
        $(this).remove();
    });
    // Stops click event from occuring in parent elements i.e. the <li> element
    event.stopPropagation();
});

// Adding a new todo from text input
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
    // Assigning the event keypress to the "Enter" key (which has a value of 13)
    if (event.which === 13) {
        // Grabbing the new todo to be added from the input field
        var newTodo = $(this).val();
        // Clears text input
        $(this).val("");
        // Creates a new <li> to add to the end of list of current todos
        $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></span> " + newTodo + "</li>")
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family: Montserrat;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #24c6dc, #514a9d);
background: linear-gradient(to left, #24c6dc, #514a9d);
font-weight: lighter;
}

h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 300;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none; 
}

li {
    margin: 1.5% auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #C06CB4;
}

/* Will style every other <li> */
li:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #6C5B7B;
}

li:hover span {
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
}

input {
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: lighter;
    background-color: #585a5e;
    color: #dae0e5;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: -webkit-border-box;
    border-style: none;
}

/* Editing highlight border of the input field when clicked */
input:focus {
    border: 3px solid #F67280;
    outline: none;
}

input::placeholder {
    color: #dae0e5;
}

span {
    background-color: #585a5e;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.35s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}

.completed {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.hr_style {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(248, 177, 149, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

#container {
    color: #dae0e5;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #6C5B7B;
    box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px black;
    border-radius: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0.18em;
}
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/munjyong/pen/gdYPKV

Comment: Use `localStorage`. The browser will save the data on the user's disk.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to save content the user creates, is by setting up a backend together with a Database and then send the data with an HTTP Post Request from your frontend to your backend. If you want to have the easiest way to get the desired effect you can use the localStorage functionality like mentioned in the comment. The MDN Docs can explain it better than I do:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage